# Python sklearn: GMM model produces bad results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use a GMM model to classify the Iris data set. My model seems to produce inconsistent results, some runs have an accuracy of 90% and some of 33% (some even going all the way to 0%). I am not sure if the mistake occurs at the classification stage or my preprocessing or print statements for accuracy are incorrect.

I have tried changing the number of iterations and the init_params when defining the classifier. I am using scikit-learn version 0.21.3 and Python 3.7.0

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM


def data_processor(input_file):
    data = []
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            if line[-1] == 'Iris-setosa':
                line[-1] = 0
            elif line[-1] == 'Iris-versicolor':
                line[-1] = 1
            elif line[-1] == 'Iris-virginica':
                line[-1] = 2
            data.append(line)

    return np.array(data, dtype=float)


x, y = data_processor('iris.txt')[:, :-1], data_processor('iris.txt')[:, -1]
# split data into 5 chucnks, 80% used for training and 20% for testing
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
train_index, test_index = next(iter(skf.split(x, y)))
x_train, y_train = x[train_index], y[train_index]
x_test, y_test = x[test_index], y[test_index]
# calculate number of components in data set using number of classes
num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))
# build classifier and fit model
classifier = GMM(n_components=num_classes, covariance_type='full',
                 max_iter=200)
classifier.fit(x_train)

# Make predictions and print accuracy
y_train_pred = classifier.predict(x_train)
accuracy_training = np.mean(y_train_pred.ravel() == y_train.ravel()) * 100
print('Accuracy on training data =', accuracy_training)

y_test_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
accuracy_testing = np.mean(y_test_pred.ravel() == y_test.ravel()) * 100
print('Accuracy on testing data =', accuracy_testing)
```

The number of test data is 150 rows, 50 per class. Previously with different models on the same data set, I was getting an accuracy of around 90-93%.

The input file contains data in this format: 5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,Iris-virginica

I have also tried to scale the data using:
    `x = preprocessing.scale(x)`

The data now looks as follows:

```
x[0] = [-0.90068117  1.03205722 -1.3412724  -1.31297673] 
y[0] = 0.0
```

However, this did not affect the accuracy.